# Testng eclipse remote debugging?

Tags: eclipse, testng, remote-debugging, testng-eclipse

I am able to debug testng when the code is in my local box and I build it on my localhost box with the simulator. I am trying to see if there is any way I can debug testng by adding debug points in eclipse giving a remote build . (Eg: like remote java application debug).

Comment: Jboss, WebSphere, GlassFish, Tomcat (or none of the above) - basically trying to determine your application hosting container if there is one

Comment: It's on tomcat.

Comment: I'll see if I can find you an example

Comment: Actually, just have a look at this, pretty straight forward [remote debugging tomcat with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835612/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse)

Comment: The one above is for remote debugging a java project. Testng has only a debug option but I couldn't find a machine or remote option endpoint for it. I have run it on my localhost.

Comment: Yeah, not finding bunch on the internet for that.  While you're in eclipse some of [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-testng.html) might be helpful. Actually this looks like it might solve your problem [debug testng java code in eclipse that uses ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001802/debug-testng-java-code-in-eclipse-that-uses-ant)