# Can't debug beforeSuite method on IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I am running simple automation code using TestNG. My lines of code are being printed to the console log and are being performed - yet I'm unable to debug any of the lines.

What is preventing me from debugging my code even though it works?

```
@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters({ "suite-param" })
public void beforeSuite(ITestContext testContext, @Optional String suiteFile) throws Exception {
    ConsoleLogger.info("------- Inititiating Suite " + testContext.getSuite().getName() + " --------");
    int nnn = 333;
    testDBAndOtherSettings();
}
```

My code compiles and I'm able to run TestNG tests methods and get results from them. Why I can't debug my own code?

Note: in "testDBAndOtherSettings" method I using DataOutputStream. I try to open a connection and do this:

```
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write( postData );
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001802/debug-testng-java-code-in-eclipse-that-uses-ant

Comment: I'm working with a POM, don't have a build.xml file. Please tell me what should I do.

Comment: What exactly is not working? how do you launch debug in IDE? How you build the code before debugging?

Comment: I'm unable to debug the code that is shown above. I'm able to debug other methods I wrote, be not the code inside beforeSuite method. My code has an effect, I see it prints to the console.

Comment: What do you mean by `unable to debug` exactly? Do breakpoints do not hit or another issue? Also add information about how you build and launch debug session.

Comment: Unable to debug = I can place breakpoints, but they don't hit. I am using Java 8 and my IDEA version is 2018.2.4. I build by clicking build and debug like you normally debug - just hit the debug mode.

Comment: Your code apparently uses TestNG and it seems that you will need to install a plugin in your IDE to make sure that it is supported: https://testng.org/doc/idea.html. Can you check whether this is already installed in your IDE?

Comment: It's installed, I'm running and writing TestNG test methods.

Comment: At first, does beforeSuite method even called? I mean do you see that message in logs? Where you placed that method? In a test class or in an external file?

Comment: The method works, I can see prints to the log / console. The method is inside a test class.

Comment: I've tested with IDEA versions 2018.2.7 (this is only available) and 2019.2.3 and with different TestNG versions from 6.8.8 until 7.0.0 and unfortunately I couldn't reproduce. Some things to check. Enure yourself that breakpoint is enabled and if it has condition than the condition is fine. Some time ago I got a strange behaviour when UI showed but it was ignored. When I removed and put that breakpoint again helped  me.

Comment: @zforgo - please see my new edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem use with my VM options. I had to add this option in order to be able to debug the code:

```
-DforkMode=never
```

I'm running testNG via a POM file, and without this configuration it won't let me debug.